# Populating an optional "has many" relationship

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to have EF populate an optional "has many" relationship but I always come up with an empty list.

Here's both models' definitions.

```
public class CustomerInfo : BaseModel
{
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; } = new List<PhoneNumber>();


        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber : BaseModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumberType PhoneNumberType { get; set; }


    public Guid CustomerInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerInfo CustomerInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried configuring the relationship as such in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Models.PhoneNumber>()
                .HasOne(a => a.CustomerInfo)
                .WithMany(a => a.PhoneNumbers)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.Id);
            

modelBuilder.Entity<Models.CustomerInfo>()
               .HasMany(a => a.PhoneNumbers)
               .WithOne(a => a.CustomerInfo)
               .HasForeignKey(a => a.CustomerInfoId);
```

Ideally, when I do `DbSet<CustomerInfo>.ToList()` for example, I'd like the `PhoneNumber` list to be populated, which is not working so far. The collection is always empty.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Probably you are looking for [AutoInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that indeed does work, thanks.